# Change the sender in outlook using C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I have an application that will be installed on a server and it is connected to the internet. Microsoft Outlook will be installed as well. The system will handle requests from 5 different departments and each department has its own email address.

I have seen this code, [Microsoft Outlook Send and Email Automation C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365476/microsoft-outlook-send-and-email-automation-c-sharp) so i know how to send an email using Outlook, but the problem I am facing is changing the sender of the email.  How do I setup the configuration of Outlook for each department that needs to send from C#? Is there a way to change the user logged in or something?

Comment: You might not want to go the outlook way. Just using SMTP would be easier to port, use and administrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Outlook to connect to an Exchange server, you can use the [Exchange Web Services Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) (and particularly the [`EmailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) class) to connect directly to the Exchange server without having to worry about configuring the Outlook client on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Outlook has a property where you can get the list of accounts mapped to it. based on your configuration you can pick up the email sender and send the email.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Accounts accounts = oMsg.Session.Accounts;                
 for (int i = 1; i <= accounts.Count; i++)
            {
                string accountfound = accounts[i].DisplayName.ToLower();
                if (accountname.ToLower() == accountfound)
                {

                    found = true;
                    oMsg.SendUsingAccount = accounts[i]; 
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipient = oMsg.Session.CreateRecipient(accountfound);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use classes in  [System.Net.Mail namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx)  to send an email using SMTP.
This way you can change the from address based on department on whose behalf you will  send an email

Comment: The Interop way to open outlook application is non trivial. But you need not configure the details like the smtp server etc everytime as outllok profile will already have the same.

Comment: mmmm, i dont want to use this, because i want all the data to be sotred in my outlook too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail on behalf on a 3rd person from Outlook, I think you must configure these accounts in Outlook.

The MailItem object has a Sender property you can use to set the sender. This property is in fact an AddressEntry object, which you need to retreive from Outlook.

In the [MSDN Documentation for AddressEntry object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.aspx), you can find examples on how to do it in the other resources section.

Comment: this could be a solution, but i prefer the exchange solution, much better, thanks :)